# How many of the three natives are bears and how many are packers?

Tags: puzzle

In a certain mythical community, Bears always lie and Packers always tell the truth. A stranger meets three natives And asks the first if he is a bear. The first native answers the question. The second native reports that the first native denied being a bear. Then the third native states that the first native really is a bear.

Comment: This has nothing to do with (geometry), so I'll edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: Well our geometry teacher introduced the class with this problem. Sorry I can't hashtag accordingly to pleasure :)

Comment: @Brian: I have no idea what this has to do with logic either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: OK.  I put that there because they're often called Raymond Smullyan (style) logic puzzles.  I'm fine with removing the tag, though.

Comment: I think the correct tag is Lake-Michigan-football-teams.

Answer (score 3):

This is a weird outfit for a Raymond Smullyan puzzle to be wearing.

The first native, whether a Bear or a Packer, will invariably deny being a Bear.  Thus, the second native is telling the truth and is a Packer.  The third native's claim that the first native is a Bear could be the truth, in which case the first native is a Bear and the third is a Packer; or, it could be a lie, in which case the first native is a Packer and the third is a Bear.

In either case, there are two Packers and one Bear.